# One to Many and One to One on same entities

Tags: entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

**Business Case**

We have a shirt that can be ordered in several different colors: Yello; White; Orange; Blue; Green; Red;
However, only one color can be selected as the default for a shirt.

**Implementation**

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Shirt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Color DefaultColor { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Color> AvailableColors { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ColorCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HexCode { get; set; }

    public int ShirtId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shirt Shirt { get; set; }
}


public class ShirtContext : DbContext
{
    public ShirtContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Shirt> Shirts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Shirt>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.DefaultColor)
            .WithRequiredDependent(c => c.Shirt);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Color>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Shirt)
            .WithMany(o => o.AvailableColors)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Issue**

`System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: 'Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'ShirtPortal.Data.Color_Shirt' was not loaded because the type 'ShirtPortal.Data.Color' is not available.'`

Can I please have assistance in setting up the foreign key relationship in my entities to match my business case?

Comment: Your problem is `public virtual Shirt Shirt { get; set; }` is not right. You define, that one color can only be the default color of one shirt, wich is wrong. If i got your right there?